# AngularJS Animation on Index Change

Tags: angularjs, css, jquery-animate

I'm having an issue working with AngularJS and CSS3 animations.

I currently have a ng-repeat of items that are styled depending on their index. I have the appropriate CSS3 animation properties in place, but I can't seem to get the items to animate when the $index of each item changes (through orderBy).

Here's my ng-repeat list:

```
<li ng-repeat="video in videos | orderObjectBy:'order'" ng-style="{left: (($index * 160) + ($index * 15) + 'px')}">
    {{ video.title }}
</li>
```

My CSS3:

```
ul li {
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease !important;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease !important;
    transition: all 3s ease !important;
}
```

My orderObjectBy filter:

```
.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
    return function(input, attribute) {
        if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

        var array = [];
        for(var objectKey in input) {
            array.push(input[objectKey]);
        }

        array.sort(function(a, b){
            a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
            b = parseInt(b[attribute]);

            if (!a && b) return 1;
                else if (a && !b) return -1;
                else if (a === b) return 0;
                else return (a > b) ? 1 : (b > a ? -1 : 0)

        });

        return array;
    }
});
```

And here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/Y8L5L/

As you can see in the JSFiddle, when you click on a video, it "jumps" to the front, because its index is changed. This is what I want to animate - instead of it jumping.

Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You must **configure your animation CSS code** before, as animations guide says, and you're using ngRepeat, so, you should read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#usage_animations.

See a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VXg7x0PXDyNw5YEbbDLI. On my Plunker I am using a ngRepeat too, so you should see the example after read.

Comment: This has nothing to do with animating by $index, therefore it is not a valid answer. For those interested, I ended up using TinySort (http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) and animating through that (calculating the "before" position, and animating from that to the "after" position).